# Phage the Untouchable as a Commander?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I was looking through the Black Legends with thoughts of building a mono-black EDH deck, when I came across [Phage the Untouchable](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Phage%20the%20Untouchable). Am I right in assuming that if she is cast from the command zone, you lose the game? (As the command zone is not considered your hand.) Is there any way to get her from the command zone into your hard or graveyard so you could cast her without losing the game?

The only one I can come up with is having a [Platinum Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Angel) in play, so you don't lose the game when you cast her.

Comment: Torpor Orb works too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're correct in assuming that you would lose the game. Casting [Phage the Untouchable](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Phage%20the%20Untouchable) from the command zone would be a sorcery-speed "Summon Game Loss" spell.

As Affe points out, she could be countered when you play her, which would put her in your graveyard (or library, depending on the counter spell used). You'd still need to get her back to your hand to cast her, though.

If you have [Platinum Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Angel) you can't lose the game and it will make Phage's ability do nothing, [Sundial of the Infinite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sundial%20of%20the%20Infinite) in response to the enter the battle field trigger will fizzle all triggers on the stack, or [Torpor Orb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Torpor%20Orb) stops her enter the battle field from ever going off.

Comment: I suspected as much. Can you think of any creative ways to get her from the command zone to your hand or graveyard?

Comment: The only way to play a card from the command zone is to cast it. I think having the Platinum Angel is the only way you could safely do so.

Comment: And it's in zone, so you can't fetch it with Ring of Maru'f or Death Wish, which let you get cards from outside the game. I guess she's pretty useless as a general, then.

Comment: It doesn't *have to* be your general. Why not stick it in your deck and fetch it with a tutor?

Comment: Also note you don't lose for casting her, she triggers on entering the battlefield.  If you can arrange to have her countered (you totally wanted to pay 14 for a Chalice of the Void, right?) she will go to GY and you can go from there.

Comment: @Affe Good point. As long as she's not Dissipated, which would just send her back to the command zone.

Comment: In Black, there's always Withering Boon available to counter her too...

Comment: Perhaps update the answer with the Command Beacon: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405180

Answer (score 12):

[Torpor Orb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Torpor%20Orb) should work. You could make the deck have a minor focus on creatures that normally are a pain to get out, like [Leveler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leveler)...

Comment: Welcome to the site, Paul! Good catch on the Torpor Orb. :)

Comment: Sundial of the Infinite is another colorless option; if your turn ends in response to Phage's trigger, you don't lose.

Comment: Yeah, you would need several cards along the lines of Toppor Orb and Sundial, because you won't have much chance of ever seeing any 1 card.

Answer (score 9):

Casting her from your command zone results with a resounding **you lose the game**, **if** she enters play.  There are several ways to still use her effectively.

I will list a few ways below that will help you to "Make it Work".  It is not the strongest style, but black has the tutors to pull it off if you really want to do it.  It is funny to see the look on people's face when you reveal Phage as your commander.  They don't know whether or not to take you seriously at first, but some might realize how big of a threat you are when you throw down a pair of [Lightning Greaves](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Greaves).

A few ways that prevent the loss are (there may be a few others, but this is all I can think of off the top of my head and I can't look through my deck at the moment):

- Having **[Platinum Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Angel)** in play (You can not lose)
- Giving one of your opponents **[Abyssal Persecutor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Abyssal%20Persecutor)** (keeps their opponents, you, from losing)
- Having a **[Torpor Orb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Torpor%20Orb)** in play (Phage's enter the battlefield ability does not trigger)
- Having a **[Sundial of the Infinite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sundial%20of%20the%20Infinite)** in play (End you turn in response to her ability going on the stack
- Having Phage countered by an effect, such as **[Nether Void](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nether%20Void)** or **[Withering Boon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Withering%20Boon)**/[Dash Hope](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dash%20Hope)  so she goes to graveyard (choose to let her go to graveyard and use one of black's many ways to get her back into your hand to hard cast from there)

Comment: You need to explain how to give your opponents a creature in Black to include Abyssal Persector. Red and Blue are capable of doing this, but I cannot think of a way of doing so in Black off the top of my head.

Comment: Endless Whispers

Comment: If you're going to use Endless Whispers, you may as well take advantage of the [Endless Whispers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=50129) + [Phage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=106427) = Win the Game Combo. ;-) (Or make someone lose if it's multiplayer…)

Comment: Dash hopes won't usually work... an opponent would happily pay 5 life to instantly make you lose.

Answer (score 4):

Hyppy's exactly right: the command zone isn't your hand, so casting Phage the Untouchable will cause you to lose the game.

Unfortunately, **there are very few ways to get around Phage's drawback in a mono-black deck**. The options available to you include [Platinum Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Angel), [Torpor Orb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Torpor%20Orb) [Sundial of the Infinite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sundial%20of%20the%20Infinite), and some truly awkward counter-your-own-Phage-and-then-[Disentomb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Disentomb)-her shenanigans. I don't think any of these are reliable enough to make Phage a worthwhile commander.

The easiest way to play Phage in Commander is to **use an alternative general and just dig her out**. Your options include:

- [Maralen](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Maralen) gives you the built-in ability to search for Phage, though the big downside of running her is that your opponents will tend to immediately assume your deck is an "unfair" combo deck before the game even begins. (Ditto [Griselbrand](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Griselbrand), but he's banned.)
- Cards like [Sheoldred, Whispering One](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sheoldred%2C%20Whispering%20One) and [Geth, Lord of the Vault](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Geth%2C%20Lord%20of%20the%20Vault) are less threatening but still thoroughly powerful mono-black generals.
- The black legends from Odyssey and Onslaught blocks are the closest "flavor" fit. Going whole-hog "Vorthos" here probably means playing [Cabal Patriarch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cabal%20Patriarch) as your general with Phage, [Chainer, Dementia Master](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chainer%2C%20Dementia%20Master), [Braids, Cabal Minion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Braids%2C%20Cabal%20Minion), and [Balthor the Defiled](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Balthor%20the%20Defiled) in the deck. With cards like [Cabal Coffers](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cabal%20Coffers) and [Mirari](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirari), you can still make a pretty powerful deck despite any flavor constraints. (Alternatively, you could use [Karona](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Karona) as your general and play Phage and Akroma within the deck in reference to her individual parts.)

Comment: Great recommendations!

Comment: Note: Griselbrand is currently banned in Commander, so he's no longer an option.

Answer (score 0):

Lich's Mirror should also work to get her out. Or maybe not.

Comment: Yes, this will let you put Phage on the battlefield and not lose. It's not very practical, though, since it will get shuffled into your library almost immediately, along with the rest of your permanents.